# Kendo UI inline editing: How to hide a button when other one is clicked

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a  Kendo UI grid with inline editing. I need to hide update button when edit is clicked.

```
                {
                    command: [
                              { name: "edit" },
                              {
                                  name: "update",
                                  click: function (e) {
                                      savedata();
                                  },
                              },
                              { name: "destroy" } 
                    ],
                    title: "&nbsp;",
                    width: 140,
                    attributes: { style: "text-align: center; color:Blue" },
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that kendo from box have that behavior.

What can you do:

In `edit` command add `onClick` handler where you will hide other buttons:

- in event arguments `e` there always some grid row data using which you can    find current row with selector or may be just using [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- Update button in kendo always have class `k-grid-update`, find it and hide

Comment: mark as answer that way, that will help others who faced with same problem